# Minimum working pressure of stainless fermenter to carbonate in fermenter

Tags: fermentation, carbonation, pressure

Which is the minimum working pressure to be capable to carbonate my beer inside the fermenter when the fermentation is over?

I'm about to buy a 0,1MPa (working preassure) fermenter.

Answer (score 1):

0.1 MPa is 14.8 psi, which is within the 12-18 PSI range you would need to reasonable carbonate most beers at 40-50 degF with roughly 2.0-3.0 volumes of CO2. At 14 psi and 40 degF you would be good for getting upto 2.6 volumes of CO2.

But, if you can chill down to 32 degF 0 degC then you may only need 7 or 8 PSI to get good carbonation.

See this table for a good guide to PSI/volCO2/temp/beerstyle:

http://www.kegerators.com/carbonation-table.php

Comment: I think you're an order of magnitude off, 0.1 MPa = 100 kPa = 14.5 psi.

Comment: I think I may have mistyped that into google to do the unit conversion, you are correct...I will fix my answer.